# Folding indexed functors with access to contextual data

Tags: haskell, traversal, functor

This is a question about traversing mutually recursive data types. I am modeling ASTs for a bunch of mutually recursive datatypes using Indexed Functor as described in this gist [here](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/af856be6cf816e08da95). This works well enough for my intended purposes.

Now I need to transform my data structure with data flowing top-down. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776420/top-down-recursion-schemes) is an SoF question asked in the context of Functor where it's shown that the carrier of the algebra can be a function that allows one to push data down during traversal. However, I am struggling to use this technique with Indexed Functor. I think my data type needs to be altered but I am not sure how.

Here is some code that illustrates my problem. Please note, that I am not including mutually recursive types or multiple indexes as I don't need them to illustrate the issue.

setDepth should change every (IntF n) to (IntF depth). The function as written won't type check because  kind ‘AstIdx -> *’ doesn't match ‘Int -> Expr ix’. Maybe I am missing something but I don't see a way to get around this without relaxing the kind of f to be less restrictive in IxFunctor but that seems wrong.

Any thoughts, suggestions or pointers welcome!

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}

infixr 5 ~>

type f ~> g = forall i. f i -> g i

class IxFunctor (f :: (k -> *) -> k -> *) where
  imap :: (a ~> b) -> (f a ~> f b)

-- Indexed Fix
newtype IxFix f ix = IxIn {ixout :: f (IxFix f) ix}

-- Fold
icata :: IxFunctor f => (f a ~> a) -> (IxFix f ~> a)
icata phi = phi . imap (icata phi) . ixout

-- Kinds of Ast
data AstIdx = ExprAst | TypeAst

-- AST
data ExprF (f :: AstIdx -> *) (ix :: AstIdx) where
  IntF :: Int -> ExprF f ExprAst
  AddF :: f ExprAst -> f ExprAst -> ExprF f ExprAst

type Expr = IxFix ExprF

instance IxFunctor ExprF where
  imap f (IntF n) = IntF n
  imap f (AddF a b) = AddF (f a) (f b)

-- Change (IntF n) to (IntF (n + 1)).
add1 :: Expr ix -> Expr ix
add1 e = icata go e
  where
    go :: ExprF Expr ix -> Expr ix
    go (IntF n) = IxIn (IntF (n + 1))
    go (AddF a b) = IxIn (AddF a b)

{-
-- Change (IntF n) to (IntF depth)
-- Doesn't type check
setDepth :: Expr ix -> Expr ix
setDepth e = icata ((flip go) 0) e
  where
    --  byDepthF :: TreeF a (Integer -> Tree Integer) -> Integer -> Tree Integer
    --  byDepthF :: TreeF a (Integer -> Tree Integer) -> Integer -> Tree Integer ix
    go :: ExprF (Int -> Expr ix) ix -> Int -> Expr ix
    go (IntF n) d = IxIn (IntF d)
    go (AddF a b) d = IxIn (AddF (a d) (b d))
-}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you're trying to set each `IntF` node to its depth *within the tree* (like the `byDepthF` function from the linked question) rather than to some fixed integer argument named `depth`.

If so, I think you're probably looking for something like the following:

```
newtype IntExpr ix = IntExpr { runIntExpr :: Int -> Expr ix }

setDepth :: Expr ix -> Expr ix
setDepth e = runIntExpr (icata go e) 0
  where
    go :: ExprF IntExpr ix -> IntExpr ix
    go (IntF n) = IntExpr (\d -> IxIn (IntF d))
    go (AddF a b) = IntExpr (\d -> IxIn (AddF (runIntExpr a (d+1)) (runIntExpr b (d+1)))
```

That is, you need to define a `newtype` that serves as the indexed first type parameter to `ExprF`, passing the index through the `Int ->` reader.  The rest is just wrapping and unwrapping.

Comment: Yes, my intent was to set IntF value to depth.